# Bootstrap Simple Transition Example

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap in my site, and want to add cool transitions between pages instead of href or window.location =. I understand from the bootstrap website it's possible out-of-the-box with bootstrap.

Would expected a simple example would be very accessible, but can't seem to find any.

Can anyone show me how?

Thanks

Comment: Where in the Bootstrap's website is it said that it's posible out of the box? Just curious

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such behaviour is possible out of the box.
The solution can be to add a listener to all links, so before the new page is load, the old one has been hidden:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('*').fadeOut();
});
```

Next you add a DOM modification listener which will hide every new created object. This can look like (*note: as far as I know DOMSubtreeModified event is now deprecated, but as far as I know it's the only solution which doesn't require 3rd party extensions, that's why I suggested it. The 'right' way would be to use some jQuery plugin like livequery*):

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    // hide new element
})
```

And the last action is to show all elements, so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').fadeIn();
});
```

And the obvious thing is that you would need to include this script in every template

Comment: Bootstrap seem to have transitions.js (even though I couldn't find docs about it).
Thanks for this answer.

Comment: As far as I know transitions.js is a file which is required for transition effect itself on various components (e.g. changing tab in tab panel), but it won't give you your desired effect out of the box

Comment: @LiorZ Look what I found: http://dailytekk.com/2012/02/24/why-web-accessibility-matters-and-how-it-can-benefit-your-business-or-website/ . Is it the effect you're looking for?

Comment: Check their page's source to know. However I think it's at least very similar to my idea